# eigen，Is there a better way to compute ABA.transpose(), or with less computational cost?

Tags: eigen3

Suppose A:r*c, B:c*c.
We want get S=ABA.tranpose(), the multiplication time is: r*c*c + c*c*r.
Since S is symmetric, then we only need triangularUpper or triangularLower part of S.

Method 1:
let D = AB, then we only need to compute upper part of DA.transpose(), which can save c*c*r/2 multiplication times.
So the problem is: is there a way to only COMPUTE upper part of matrix multiplication with two different size matrix in eigen?

Method 2:
Let B=LL.transpose(), then S = (BL)(BL).transpose.
As supposed in Better way to calculate A * A.transpose() ?
We can get S by: S.selfadjointView().rankUpdate(BL.transpose()).
But the problem is the LLT decomposition cost is O(n3), the loss overweighs the gain.

Thanks for any useful suggestions.

tried:
1、use Method2

expecting：
1、Solution for Method1, or any suggestion for Method1.

Thanks.

Comment: The LLT decomposition can still be worth it if A is much bigger than B. Note that Eigen doesn't parallelize rank updates unless you link to a BLAS library that does (like OpenBLAS). If LLT fails, LDLT also works.

Comment: Note also that since Eigen matrices are by default stored in [column-major order](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html), the multiplication would be more efficient when expressed as `(B.transpose() * A).transpose() * A`. Of course this requires transposing the underlying storage of A.

Comment: 1、 In my application, A:rc, B:cc, r,c < 200, r<=c. 2、I will try decomposition of B using LLT and the new expression (B.transpose() * A).transpose() * A . Thanks again : )

Comment: Make sure to use the `triangularView<Eigen::Lower>()` on the `L` matrix when multiplying `B * L`. That saves a lot